# Crazy battery drain and heating on new Windows 10 mobile builds?

Tags: insider-preview, battery, nokia-lumia-930

My Lumia 930 updated to the latest slow branch insider preview build last friday and since then it has been running through the battery a lot faster than before and runs a bit warmer than before even when it's on idle. At first I thought it was because of my recent data plan upgrade from 3G to 4G but when I forced the connection down to 3G it still drains battery like crazy. So is this a known problem or is something else messed up on my phone? And if so, are there ways to fix this?

Comment: Check `Battery usage` in Parameters->System->Battery Saver.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe I have checked it multiple times and there's nothing out of the ordinary. I've been using the phone just like I usually do. But yesterday for example, The battery lasted for under 3 hours from full charge before it was dead again. And I barely even used it to try and conserve the battery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hard reset solved the battery issue. Now the build is running all fine and dandy!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, that's a common issue. That is why preview builds are. To point out bugs and problems to Microsoft. Make sure you give a feedback, it might be useful. By the way, the latest Redstone build, 14322.1000 is so far the best version of Windows 10, you should update!